# How to update a OpenGL GLWidget embedded within Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl

I am developing a really simple application using Qt and OpenGL. The application contains a few buttons for interaction and a widget tab containing 3 pages, the first two for analyzing and processing some data and the third contains a `GLWidget` which should draw the result points in a 3d space.

At the beginning the 3d space doesn't contain any points and after all the data are processed it should draw the 3 points.

So far I have tried to call an external function to `paintGL()` to draw a solid cube at the center of the scene. The method is correctly called but the widget does not display any cube.

Here's the code for `glwidget.cpp`:

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateGL()));
    timer.start(1000);
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL(int w, int h) {
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    // Setup light
    const GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat light_position[] = {2.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f };
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DOUBLE);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, 1.0, 0.0001, 1000.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    current_view= TOP_VIEW;

}

// Display
void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glLoadIdentity();
    setView();
    if (current_view == EXPLORING_VIEW)
        calculate_lookpoint();
    gluLookAt(eyex, eyey, eyez, centerx, centery, centerz, upx, upy, upz);
    // Draw axis and add points
    drawAxis();
    int ind;
    Skyline s;
    if (s.skylineGenerated()) {
        drawCube();
        cout << "Generated" << endl;
    }
   swapBuffers();
}

void GLWidget::drawCube(void){
    cout << "Drawn\n";
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glutSolidCube(2.0);
    update();
}

// Reshape
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective (48.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 10.0, 800.0);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Place your timer initialization code at the end of the initializeGL function as you do not want your paintGL function being called before intializeGL. (Which could happen using your current code)
2. Connect your timer slot to `QGLWidget::update` instead of `QGLWidget::updateGL`. This will not only call `updateGL` for you but will allow queued paint events to be collapsed into a single event.
3. Make sure your timer.singleShot() does not return true as then the widget will only be updated once.
4. Your initializeGL should NOT take arguments. Qt is never calling your intializeGL function as it is attempting to call an initialzeGL function with NO arguments and thus it will call the base class `QGLWidget::initializeGL` instead. You should also not use a static viewport, and should handle all viewport resizing (glViewport) within an overrided `QGLWidget::resizeGL( int w, int h )`.

Comment: I have tried but it's not working. Anyway I have decided to use my original program(which works fine) and execute it within the GLWidget. So I added this line
void Sk::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    process.start("/home/user/Desktop/Test");
}

How can I display the external program within the GLWidget?

Comment: Look at my revision to the answer above. (point 4) Check this before you attempt another technique. Also, displaying an external program withing the QGLWidget doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I running out of time and I need to hand in this program as soon as possible so I thought that using my previous working program and integrating it in a widget is the best choice, do you know how can I achieve this?